# Using Converters with TemplateBinding or Relativesource Templated Parent

Tags: xaml, windows-phone, templatebinding

Hello I am using attached properties inside a ContentControl template. My approach so far is this-

**Class with Attached Property**

```
public class PlaceHolderForProfilePic : DependencyObject
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty InitialsProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Initials", typeof(string), typeof(PlaceHolderForProfilePic), new PropertyMetadata(""));
    public static string GetInitials(DependencyObject d)
    {
        return (string)d.GetValue(InitialsProperty);
    }
    public static void SetInitials(DependencyObject d, string value)
    {
        d.SetValue(InitialsProperty, value);
    }
}
```

**Control Template Declaration**

```
<ContentControl helpers:PlaceHolderForProfilePic.Initials="{Binding FullName,Converter={StaticResource placeholderConverter},ConverterParameter=initials}" Width="60" Height="60" Template="{StaticResource DefaultProfilePictureItemTemplate2}"/>
```

**Control Template Body**

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="DefaultProfilePictureItemTemplate2">
    <Grid Name="parentGrid">
         <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding helpers:PlaceHolderForProfilePic.Initials}" />
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Now I want to apply the converter INSIDE the Template Body, Not in the declaration. I know that TemplateBinding does not accept converters, so I tried to use RelativeSource Templated Parent like this-

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding helpers:PlaceHolderForProfilePic.Initials , RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, Converter={StaticResource placeholderConverter}, ConverterParameter=initials}"/>
```

But there is a BindingPathExpression error as it does not accept ":"

Is there any other way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try using syntax: {Binding Path=(helpers:PlaceHolderForProfilePic.Initials), ...} instead.